# Blinking screen on Macbook Air 2011 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, screen

I have some issue with my macbook air mid 2011 13" One day screen start blinking and flickering. This is a short video how it looks like [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN0sJ9lOplg) Only blinking, no stripes on screen or other artifacts.

Any suggestions what is the reason? Screen, motherboard, I/O board? How can I fix it without changing the screen?

Comment: Did you try Apple Hardware Test? See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257 for more information about performing a AHT

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is a screen issue with the backlighting failing. Your only option will be to replace the screen.